# Hyperlink works for one sheet that was imported but not for the rest?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, spreadsheet

I created a macro that would select multiple sheets by sheet name from different Excel files, import them into the target Excel workbook and then create a hyperlink with the name being the imported Excel sheet file. It works for the first imported sheet but for the rest, when I try clicking on the reference, I get a pop up saying reference is not valid. Also another thing that happens is that it overrides the second Hyperlink with the same name as the first.

```
Sub ImportSheetsFromFolder()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim selectedFile As Variant
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    
    
    
    ' Prompt user to select folder
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select Folder Containing Excel Files"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            folderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "No folder selected. Exiting."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Set target workbook (current workbook)
    Set targetWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Prompt user for sheet name to import
    sheetName = InputBox("Enter the name of the sheet to import:", "Sheet Name")
    If sheetName = "" Then
        MsgBox "No sheet name provided. Exiting."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Loop through each file in the selected folder
    selectedFile = Dir(folderPath & "\*.xlsx")
    Do While selectedFile <> ""
        ' Open source workbook
        Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "\" & selectedFile)
        
        ' Check if the sheet exists in the source workbook
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = sourceWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName)
       
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        ' If the sheet exists, import it into the target workbook
       
          If Not ws Is Nothing Then
        ws.Copy After:=targetWorkbook.Sheets(targetWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        
        End If
        
       Worksheets("Hyperlink").Select
       Range("A1").Select
       
   'Create hyperlink for each sheet that was imported into seperate sheet in target WB
   For Each ws In Worksheets
     ' Check if the sheet name is not one of the excluded sheets
    If ws.Name <> "TB 460201" And ws.Name <> "Hyperlink" And ws.Name <> "Cover sheet" And ws.Name <> "Supporting details" And ws.Name <> "Data" Then
   
    ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveCell, Address:="", SubAddress:="" & ws.Name & "!A1" & "", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=sourceWorkbook.Name
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
   End If
   
   Next ws
    
       
        ' Close the source workbook without saving changes
        sourceWorkbook.Close False
        
        ' Move to the next file
        selectedFile = Dir
         
    Loop
   
    MsgBox "Import complete."
    
     End Sub
```

Expecting hyperlink. Hyperlink should have name of Source workbook.

Answer (score 0):

The code has `Range("A1").Select` inside the `Do` loop, so it is starting over from `A1` every time a new file is opened, and overwriting the hyperlinks from the previous file. If you step through it, you will see your expected hyperlink names, then see them get overwritten by the next hyperlink names.

Also within the `Do` loop, it loops through every worksheet in your target workbook, every time you open a new file. That `For Each ws` should not be used, because at that point you are only concerned with the current `ws`.

I've commented out those 3 lines `Range("A1").Select` and the `For Each ws In Worksheets`. It should work as expected.

```
Sub ImportSheetsFromFolder()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim selectedFile As Variant
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    
    
    
    ' Prompt user to select folder
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select Folder Containing Excel Files"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            folderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "No folder selected. Exiting."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Set target workbook (current workbook)
    Set targetWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Prompt user for sheet name to import
    sheetName = InputBox("Enter the name of the sheet to import:", "Sheet Name")
    If sheetName = "" Then
        MsgBox "No sheet name provided. Exiting."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Loop through each file in the selected folder
    selectedFile = Dir(folderPath & "\*.xlsx")
    Do While selectedFile <> ""
        ' Open source workbook
        Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "\" & selectedFile)
        
        ' Check if the sheet exists in the source workbook
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = sourceWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName)
       
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        ' If the sheet exists, import it into the target workbook
       
          If Not ws Is Nothing Then
        ws.Copy After:=targetWorkbook.Sheets(targetWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        
        End If
        
       Worksheets("Hyperlink").Select
'       Range("A1").Select <--Remove
       
   'Create hyperlink for each sheet that was imported into seperate sheet in target WB
'   For Each ws In Worksheets <--Remove
     ' Check if the sheet name is not one of the excluded sheets
    If ws.Name <> "TB 460201" And ws.Name <> "Hyperlink" And ws.Name <> "Cover sheet" And ws.Name <> "Supporting details" And ws.Name <> "Data" Then
   
    ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveCell, Address:="", SubAddress:="" & ws.Name & "!A1" & "", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=sourceWorkbook.Name
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
   End If
   
'   Next ws <--Remove
    
       
        ' Close the source workbook without saving changes
        sourceWorkbook.Close False
        
        ' Move to the next file
        selectedFile = Dir
         
    Loop
   
    MsgBox "Import complete."
    
     End Sub
```

Comment: Actually now, its referencing just one sheet. Example, I would ask for Support sheet to be imported. Problem is that they are multiple sheets with title support sheet so when imported, it comes up as Support (2) Support (3) so its not linking to those sheets